# The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request ( The data is invalid. ): Code base Works on one machine but not another

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008

This will probably be an environmental issue but I'm stumped as where to start.

I'm attempting to call a a webservice on an external server in an asp.net web app while debugging in VS2008. The **exact same code/project** works on one machine calling the server but on another machine (my new one) it fails with the 400 Bad request (data is invalid) error.

Both machines are running Windows 7. What should I be looking for as differences in the two machines that could be contributing to this problem?

**Edit** Deleting the webreference in the project and re-creating the webreference had no effect

**Update**

I went to use Fidler2 to inpect the request and response which resulted in the error going away. Things are beginning to point to an internet proxy issue.

Comment: Are you able to enter the web service address on the machine that is not working and append `?wsdl` to the end of the address and receive the WSDL back or no?

Comment: Second, turn off friendly HTTP error messages in your browser (in IE it is `Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced` and then un-check the `show friendly HTTP errors` check box.

Comment: @KarlAnderson yes, when accessing throguh a browser the WSDL is returned on the suspect machine and friendlies are already off

Comment: Are you using the exact same browser between the two machines and the same version?

Comment: @KarlAnderson, browser shouldn't be an issue, the error is thrown by an asp.net web app calling the web service. Also the error occurs regardless of browser. Both machines have a range of browsers installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an Internet Proxy issue. The suspect machine had be configured to manually use a proxy server. Turning this off: Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Connections Tab -> Lan Settings Button, and enabling "Automatically detect settings" has fixed the problem.